# iOS FacebookSDK's Scrumptious sample application doesn't work because it always recieves FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.1

The question is straightforward.

I have run the application without modifying anything on an iPhone 5, iPhone 4S and the simulator, all running iOS7.

I have configured my FB account in Settings so that when I try to login it takes that account. The problem is that when the alert view for permissions appears

[image: Permissions alert view] , even if I select *OK*

(for accepting), it enters the *loginView:handleError* delegate method with the error being **FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled**.

The question is here too: [Similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21249672/always-return-error-fberrorcategoryusercancelled-while-login-with-facebook-in-my), but it has no answers.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? My was reject for this, and I can't reconstruct it. Thanks

Comment: I don't have this problem anymore. After a day or two, it got solved by itself, I didn't do anything. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue turned out to be missing Facebook app settings.  (Specifically, the iOS / Bundle ID settings.)

[(See answer here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12671420/ios-6-facebook-posting-procedure-ends-up-with-remote-app-id-does-not-match-stor)

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

There is an underlying error that simply surfaces as this generic `FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled`. To me, it looks like poor design in the Facebook SDK to effectively swallow the error in this way.

You can debug this by setting a breakpoint in the delegate where you get the error.

Then go up the stack to the method inside the Facebook SDK that generated the error -- `requestAccessToFacebookAccountStore:defaultAudience:isReauthorize:appID:session:handler`.
(Or just find that method and set the breakpoint there. Alternatively, You could try calling `requestAccessToAccountsWithType` yourself and see the error there.)

You can then inspect the underlying error in the debugger

```
(lldb) po error
Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: The app must ask for a basic read permission  like email at install time." UserInfo=0xb6bfd70 {NSLocalizedDescription=The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: The app must ask for a basic read permission  like email at install time.}
```

Comment: What I do if I can't reproduce this issue but Apple keeps rejecting me for this reason ? Thank you.